# How can I compute the total derivative of a time-varying quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, control-theory

Let $x : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^n$ be a time-varying vector and let $P : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be a time-varying symmetric matrix, such that $P(t) = P^T(t)$ for every $t \in [0,\infty)$. Moreover, let
$$
V(x(t),P(t)) = x^T(t)P(t)x(t)
$$
How can I compute the following total derivative in terms of $\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$ and $\frac{dP}{dt}(t)$?
$$
\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),P(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}\{x^T(t)P(t)x(t)\}
$$
Here is what I tried so far:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\{x^T(t)P(t)x(t)\} &= \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x(t),P(t)) \frac{dx}{dt}(t) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial P}(x(t),P(t)) \frac{dP}{dt}(t) 
\end{align}
I don't think this expression is correct, because the second summand is a matrix, while the first summand is a scalar. I can compute the first summand as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x(t),P(t)) \frac{dx}{dt}(t) &= x^T(t)(P(t) + P^T(t))\frac{dx}{dt}(t) \\
&= 2x^T(t)P(t)\frac{dx}{dt}(t)
\end{align}
which makes sense, since $V(x(t),P(t))$ is a scalar. In a paper that I'm reading, I find that the second summand evaluates to $$x^T(t)\frac{dP}{dt}(t)x(t)$$ However, I'm not sure where this comes from.

---

**UPDATE**

Using @TrystwithFreedom's comments, we can obtain the answer as follows. However, I'm not sure why this works, and I would appreciate either an explanation for why this method works, or another more rigorous method.
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dt}(x(t),P(t))dt &\approx V(x(t+dt),P(t+dt)) - V(x(t),P(t)) \\
&\approx x^T(t+dt)P(t+dt)x(t+dt) - x^T(t)P(t)x(t) \\
&\approx \left(x(t) + \frac{dx}{dt}(t) dt\right)^T\left(P(t) + \frac{dP}{dt} dt\right)\left(x(t) + \frac{dx}{dt}(t) dt\right) - x^T(t)P(t)x(t) \\
&\approx x^T(t)P(t)x(t) + x^T(t)P(t)\frac{dx}{dt}(t)dt + \frac{dx^T}{dt}(t) P(t)x(t) dt + \frac{dx^T}{dt}(t) P(t) \frac{dx}{dt}(t) (dt)^2 \\
&+ x^T(t) \frac{dP}{dt} x(t) dt + x^T(t)\frac{dP}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}(t) (dt)^2 + \frac{dx^T}{dt}(t) \frac{dP}{dt} x(t) (dt)^2 + \frac{dx^T}{dt}(t) \frac{dP}{dt} \frac{dx}{dt}(t) (dt)^3 \\
&- x^T(t)P(t)x(t)
\end{align}
We then remove any higher order terms such as $(dt)^2$ and $(dt)^3$ to get
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dt}(x(t),P(t))dt &= x^T(t)P(t)x(t) + x^T(t)P(t)\frac{dx}{dt}(t)dt + \frac{dx^T}{dt}(t) P(t)x(t) dt + x^T(t) \frac{dP}{dt} x(t) dt - x^T(t)P(t)x(t) \\
&= x^T(t)P(t)\frac{dx}{dt}(t)dt + \frac{dx^T}{dt}(t) P(t)x(t) dt + x^T(t) \frac{dP}{dt} x(t) dt \\
&= 2x^T(t)P(t)\frac{dx}{dt}(t)dt + x^T(t) \frac{dP}{dt} x(t) dt
\end{align}
This method is a bit "hand-wavy", as I'm not sure why it works, especially the part about removing any $(dt)^2$ and $(dt)^3$ terms.

Comment: Use the taylor series on every expression. That's it.

Comment: $x(t+dt) = x(t) + x'(t) dt$, $P(t+dt) = P(t) + P'(t) dt$ and so on

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Thanks, this worked. However, I've never seen this method before. Could you provide a reference for why it works? It only worked for me when I sent any term with the terms $(dt)^2$ and $(dt)^3$ to $0$. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: This is literally the definition of a derivative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative In the end, you have just applied the product rule, nothing else.

Comment: @KBS The definition of the derivative is a limit. How is that relevant to what I did in my update?

Comment: Just do the math and you'll see why the higher order terms can be neglected.

Comment: There are many equivalent definition of the derivative. One I used is the first order variation definition; the one where you define it through the tahlor series @mhdadk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since matrices in general do not commute, which makes the use of partial derivative and then multiplying by their time derivatives more error prone. Therefore, I would recommend to use the product rule, such that

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(x^\top\!(t)\,P(t)\,x(t)\right)=
\frac{d\,x^\top\!(t)}{dt}\,P(t)\,x(t) + x^\top\!(t)\,\frac{d\,P(t)}{dt}\,x(t) + x^\top\!(t)\,P(t)\,\frac{d\,x(t)}{dt}.
$$

Because $P(t)$ is symmetric, the first and and third term yields the same scalar value, so can also be combined. Thus the above is equivalent to

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(x^\top\!(t)\,P(t)\,x(t)\right)=
x^\top\!(t)\,\frac{d\,P(t)}{dt}\,x(t) + 2\,x^\top\!(t)\,P(t)\,\frac{d\,x(t)}{dt}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this. I just realized that you’ve essentially used the product rule twice, first on $x^T(t)$ and $P(t)x(t)$ (since this is a vector), and then on $P(t)$ and $x(t)$.

Comment: @mhdadk This is exactly what I said in one of my comments.

Comment: @KBS what you wrote is: "In the end, you have just applied the product rule, nothing else." You did not mention that the product rule was used twice.

Comment: @mhdadk it is also called the product rule when applied to [more than two terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Generalizations).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Ahh, I see. My mistake then. Thanks for pointing this out.